# Comparing names of two files in different directories

Tags: python

So I am going through two directories. For each file found, I print their name. What I want to do is make a comparison, but I can't advance since  I'm having trouble with my if statement. Let's say I have a txt file named `some` in both directories.If `some` is found in the file name, i print found. That works seperately.  My problem is the `and` operator. Both files are named `"some.txt"`, but I get nothing. Like I said, it works if I get rid of the `and` operator.

```
def compare(directory1, directory2):
    for file1, file2 in zip(os.listdir(directory1),(os.listdir(directory2))):
        if "some" in file1 and "some" in file2:
            print("found")
```

Comment: Can you add the names of the files in both directories?

Comment: Don't use `zip`. With `zip` you will only ever compare the `j-th` file from `directory1` against the `j-th` file from `directory2`

Comment: may filecmp.cmpfiles() be useful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use zip in this case. The way you are doing it, you are only comparing file1 and file2 that have the same index in your directory list.

To compare all possible pairings, simply do this:

```
def compare(directory1, directory2):
    for file1 in os.listdir(directory1):
        for file2 in os.listdir(directory2):
            if "some" in file1 and "some" in file2:
                print("found")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it, I believe:

```
def compare(directory1, directory2):
dir1 = {file for file in os.listdir(directory1)}
dir2 = {file for file in os.listdir(directory2)}
dir_common = dir1.union(dir2)
for file in dir_common:
    if "some" in file:
        print("found")
```